# Mock wrong JSON response with Pytest to raise simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError on purpose

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, mocking, pytest

I want to test exceptions with Pytest. I send an HTTP request and get a response. I want the response to be corrupt so response.json() goes to the except block. Below are the examples.

Send a request, receive a response:

```py
def send_message_json():
    # ...
    try:
        response = cls.send_message(method, url, **kwargs)
        if response:
            return response.json()  # this is what should fail
    except simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError as err:
        raise err  # this is to be achieved
```

The unit test should assert that the simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError should be raised.

```py
@mock.patch.object(Service, 'send_message_json')
def test_send_message_json_exception(mock_send):
    svc = Service()
    with pytest.raises(simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError):  # this should assert the exceptions was raised
        svc.send_message_json("GET", 'http://my.url/')
```

I fail to activate the exception raise by the pytest.mock.object. What would make .json() fail in the mock?

Comment: `@mock.patch.object(Service, 'send_message_json', side_effect=JSONDecodeError)`

Comment: @hoefling with this approach I was thinking that it will throw this error regardless what changes I make to the function. So for example, if I make changes to this method send_message_json() that shouldn't pass, will side_effect still throw an error that wouldn't be thrown otherwise??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by mocking the response of the actual request.

1. In the original question there's send_message_json() method.
2. It calls send_message() method that returns requests.Response. So I mocked the return value of send_message() that is also a mock instead of send_message_json():

```py
@mock.patch.object(Service, 'send_message')  # mock send_message instead
def test_send_message_json_exception(mock_send):
    
    svc = Service()

    mocked_response = Response()
    mocked_response.status_code = 200
    mocked_response.data = '<!doctype html>'  # so this is obviously not a JSON

    mock_send.return_value = mocked_response  # apply the mocked response here

    with pytest.raises(simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError):
        svc.send_message_json("GET", 'http://my.url/')  # this calls send_message() and returns a bad mocked requests.Response
```

3. The bad mocked requests.Response fails at mocked_response.json() in send_message_json() and raises simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError

Comment: this Response() is from which library?

Comment: @Learner it is from `requests`